# JObject converts char to int

Tags: c#, json.net

The following code

```
var x = new JObject {
  ["property1"] = 'a',
  ["property2"] = "A",
  ["property3"] = -1,
  ["property4"] = 9.9,
};
```

This returns the following values when x is examined:

97,
A,
-1,
9.9

How do I stop JSON.Net from converting the `char` value as an integer?

**UPDATE**
I've examined the code in the debugger and I've also run it in LinqPad and just dumped the result.

The problem arose when I was trying to write code to validate some input via an API, I *should* get getting a pair or doubles but as the post to the API is, potentially, out of my control, I need to properly validate it. That's when I noticed off behaviour if I was passed a `char`.

Comment: "This returns the following values when x is examined" Can you please elaborate on how you examine x exactly? With a watch in a debugger? By writing to a file? Anyway a char is nothing but a number. So what exactly are you doing that makes you wonder why this happens?

Comment: Use a string, not a char. In C# char is an integral type and in JSON there is no concept of character as a type.

Comment: See the updates to the question. I don't control the input

Comment: I read your update but the post to the API must include the content-type: application/json header for the scenario to be valid. If it is, it is not possible that you are receiving a character type.

Comment: You will never be passed a `char` because, as mentioned, that's not a type in JSON. All you have to worry about is validating a property that you see as an `int`, and educating any callers that if they pass a `char`, it'll end up as an `int`. Extending JSON is not your responsibility.

Comment: I wonder how anyone even can pass a `char` to your web-service, if not by passing a number.

Comment: Not sure why the question warranted the downvote, but, OK.

I was unaware that JSON couldn't create a char type. It seems, then, that I'm trying to solve a problem that can only occur in my C# unit tests

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I'm trying to solve a problem that can't exist except in the context of my own unit tests as when a `char` is serialized it is serialized to a single-character string.

It was the act of manually constructing the `JObject` that made the issue that I was seeing visible and this is because, as I've been told, JSON has no concept of type `char` and so, in C#, at least, assigning a `char` to a `JObject` causes the value to be saved as the `int` representation of it.